# Juniper EX 3300 Incorrectly Identifies SFP+ Transceiver Module

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex, sfp

We have 2 Juniper EX 3300 switches operating in a stack. It is running Junos 12.3R3.4. The switches have 4 SFP/SFP+ Ports. On FPC 1, PIC 1, Xcvr 0 you see a description of "SFP-FC8G-SW." However, the transceiver is a Juniper branded 10GE SFP+ SR (see image below).

The interface is up/down. On the client side the physical media indicates that it is connected but there seems to be no link layer connectivity. No traffic passes on the interface.

Here is the output of "show chassis hardware"

```
root@juniper> show chassis hardware 
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                GA021XXXXXXX      Virtual Chassis
Routing Engine 0 REV 10   750-034247   GA021XXXXXXX      EX3300 48-Port
Routing Engine 1 REV 10   750-034247   GA021XXXXXXX      EX3300 48-Port
FPC 0            REV 10   750-034247   GA021XXXXXXX      EX3300 48-Port
  CPU                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           FPC CPU
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           48x 10/100/1000 Base-T
  PIC 1          REV 10   750-034247   GA021XXXXXXX      4x GE/XE SFP+
    Xcvr 0                NON-JNPR     TED1728B11R       SFP+-10G-CU3M
    Xcvr 1       REV 01   740-021308   ALE0GT1           SFP+-10G-SR
    Xcvr 2       !        NON-JNPR     PRO3M110          SFP+-10G-CU1M
    Xcvr 3       !        NON-JNPR     PRO3M102          SFP+-10G-CU1M
  Power Supply 0                                         PS 100W AC
  Fan Tray                                               Fan Tray
FPC 1            REV 10   750-034247   GA021XXXXXXX      EX3300 48-Port
  CPU                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           FPC CPU
  PIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           48x 10/100/1000 Base-T
  PIC 1          REV 10   750-034247   GA021XXXXXXX      4x GE/XE SFP+
    Xcvr 0                NON-JNPR     PNN32WL           SFP-FC8G-SW
    Xcvr 1                NON-JNPR     TED1729BEKS       SFP+-10G-CU3M
    Xcvr 2       !        NON-JNPR     PRO3M103          SFP+-10G-CU1M
    Xcvr 3       !        NON-JNPR     PRO3M111          SFP+-10G-CU1M
  Power Supply 0                                         PS 100W AC
  Fan Tray                                               Fan Tray
```

[image: SFP+ Transceiver Module]

Comment: Maybe I am missing it, but there doesn't seem to be a question in the post.  However, have you tried this in another port or device to see if you get different results? Can you loop it back to itself?

Comment: @YLearn, sorry, the question is: What might cause this behavior? What next troubleshooting steps might I take towards finding a resolution? Juniper wants to RMA the switch. I will try what you suggest.

Comment: pull the SFP, check the serial numbers match.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo, I think Ricky and I are thinking along the same lines.  While the switch could be at fault, it is far more likely that the actual transceiver doesn't match the label on the outer metal casing.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo So, you're saying JTAC wants to RMA the switch before the Transceiver?  That's very uncommon, SFPs are (normally) the first things to go.

Comment: @RickyBeam You were correct, the serial numbers did not match, the transceiver was an 8G FC transceiver. I realized this when I put it into a "known good" port. The "show chassis hardware" updated confirming that the transceiver was mislabeled. I placed a 10G SFP+ SR module in on my trouble port and the issue is resolved.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo, please answer your own question below and mark it accepted so it doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick test: Swap the SFPs with a known working ones on the switch (if possible) and see if the condition stays with the ports or follow the SFPs.

If the other SFP works in the current "problematic SFP ports" there is less possibility of this being the switch's problem (I still could be, but just unlikely).

You can try to plug it in the other switch's too... if it's problematic there, it's almost guaranteed to be the SFP, unless you got the One-In-A-Million chance of having two switches with exactly the same freaking bug - extremely unlikely

If after all that JTAC still insist for RMA on both switches, just escalate the issue to get someone more reasonable at their end.

Edit: I've just seen that it was a mislabeling issue, you might want to mark this question as answered. :)